# Using 3rd party libraries in production

Tags: solidity, library

In the case where you wish to use a library that someone else has written for your own contract, is it generally best practice to link to the developer's own deployment of their library? Or should you deploy their code and then link to your own deployment?

I'm interested in using [this library](https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils), but they have not included an address in the readme. How would one find the address, and addresses for deployed libraries in general?

Same goes for deploying on a public test network. Is it best to use the dev's address, and if so, how do you get it?

Finally -- are deployed libraries immutable? I think I read somewhere that libraries can be upgraded. If my contracts depend on a specific library, would I then have to worry about an update to said library breaking my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People just redeploy stuff a lot. And yes, they are immutable.